# Why does the expected value of the l=lag time series observation multiplied by the white noice equal zero in a stationary autoregressive model?

Tags: time-series, expected-value, stationarity, autoregressive

Suppose we have a stationary AR(1) model. Therefore $y_{t}=b_{0}+b_{1}y_{t-1}+e_{t}$ where e is the white noise. I am just wondering why (A) $E[(y_{t-l}-\mu)e_{t}]=0$. At first, I thought that $y_{t-l}$ and e were independent, so (B) $E[(y_{t-l}-\mu)e_{t}]=E[(y_{t-l}-\mu)]E[e_{t}]$  and both would clearly equal zero, thus making the product zero. However, I saw in the textbook that the result using stationarity as a condition for (A) to hold. However, if $y_{t-l}$ and e are independent, then $E[(y_{t-l}-\mu)e_{t}]=0$ would hold regardless of stationarity. So maybe my logic in assumption (B) is flawed. Can anyone provide some clarification, or a way that I could prove this? 
Thank you in advance.